# Whats the best way to handle SVG animations on prop change?

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, reactjs

I have the two following ReactJS components:

MyGraphThingy, which acts as a container for the actual elements. It renders into an svg element with the children inside it.

MyGraphElement, which renders into a circle.

In a third component the render method returns the following:

```
<MyGraphThingy><MyGraphElement position={this.getPosition()/></MyGraphThingy>
```

where getPosition() depends on the components state. So if the relevant state of the component changes, the position of the SVG circle should change.

The question is, what is the best way to implement animation so that instead of the circle jumping from a place to another, it would transit smoothly?

The circle is just an example, the real use case involves animating pretty much all SVG properties.

No, I do not want to depend on D3 and yes, I would ideally want to handle this in MyGraphThingy triggered by a property change instead of using modules like react-animate. I should probably use some of the lifecycle methods in this, but how to implement the actual animation is what I'd like to know.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at Web Animations:

- http://www.w3.org/TR/web-animations-1/
- https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/platform/web-animations.html

Comment: web animations are not tied to react or any other framework. It's just a way of animating attributes and properties of Elements. animate is a function which can be called on any Element.
f.e. in  changePosition() you could do yourCircle.animate(...). If you provide more code i could tell you more about where to put your animation.